# Connection Closes if I define constructor for Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, constructor, signalr

I need a constructor for my Hub to connect to the DependencyInjections.
As soon as I declare a `private readonly` dependency variable and a constructor for my Hub -Even with no code inside it - I got `ConnectionClose` even before `OnConnectedAsync` runs.

Means `OnConnectedAsync` never runs!

> Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'.

```
private readonly Chatter _chatter;

public ChatHub(Chatter chatter)
{
    _chatter = chatter;
}
```

Or even

```
private readonly Chatter _chatter;

public ChatHub(Chatter chatter)
{
    //Empty
}
```

But this is OK:

```
private readonly Chatter _chatter;

public ChatHub()
{
    //Whatever...
}
```

Comment: You need to register your dependency so that it can be injected into the Hub. Chances are that it does not know about the dependency in order to inject it, which causes the error.

Comment: In situations like this, please make sure to look at the log from your server. It’s very likely that it contains some information about the actual error that is happening there. What you are seeing is just the result in the client which won’t contain much information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your dependency so that it can be injected into the Hub.

```
services.AddTransient<Chatter>();
```

Chances are that the DI container does not know about the dependency in order to inject it, which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to send in my AppSettings class. In my Startup.cs, I already had my appsettings.json class, AppSettingOptions, setup for injection for services.

```
services.Configure<AppSettingOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(AppSettingOptions.SettingsName));
```

Yet I had forgotten to use the IOptions data type as a parameter instead of the AppSettingOptions data type.

```
public ClassA(IOptions<AppSettingOptions> appSettingOptions)
```

For additional debugging if this does not solve you issue, if you set the parameter to a default value of null you should be able to at least step into the constructor on the server side instead of finding the error on the client side.

```
public ClassA(IOptions<AppSettingOptions> settingOptions = null)
```